# Лишняя цифра в выводе, как?

Tags: java

Объясните пожалуйста, почему у меня лишняя цифра в выводе?
Как убрать лишнюю двойку вверху?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, };
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
}   
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            
            System.out.println(arr[i] + " ");
           
}
    }
}

Вывод:
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 2 
4
6 
8 
10 
12 
14 
16 
18 
20
```

Comment: Добавьте `System.out.println(" ");` перед вторым циклом.

Comment: Я не знаю, как можно было не увидеть, в чём проблема. Бесполезный вопрос.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, пробел-то нафига?

Comment: @Qwertiy, на всякий случай, я не был уверен в том, что сделается без пробела)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а чего б ему не сделаться? Если б с пустыми строками не работало, это была бы какая-то жесть. И там вроде вообще перегрузка без параметра есть - `System.out.println()`;

Comment: @Qwertiy, я столько раз в, казалось бы, очевидных вещах обжигался, что теперь на всё дую)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну ваша цифры не лишняя. В первом цикле вы печатает в строку без переноса и потом начинаете печатать с переносом строки, но с той же позиции. Ваша 2-ка это 2-ка из второго цикла.

Вам стоит перед вторым циклом добавить перенос:

```
System.out.println("");
```

Либо если вам 2-ка вообще не нужна второй цикл нужно начинать не с 0 значения, а с 1ого. Но правда перенос все равно нужен.

```
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20,};
        System.out.print(" ");
        for (int value : arr) {
            System.out.print(value + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int value : arr) {
            System.out.println(value + " ");
        }
    }
```

Наверно такая задумка была?